# How automate Variable Payments Between Customers and Clients Using Stripe in a DRF Backend

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am relatively new to Stripe payments and have encountered a challenge while working on a Django Rest Framework (DRF) backend application. In this application, customers are making payments to their respective clients, with each payment having a different amount. I need to automate this payment process.

Here are the specific requirements:

```
Customers should have the flexibility to select the date or frequency of payments to their clients.
Payments need to be automatically dispatched from the customer to the client on the specified date or at the chosen frequency.
Customers should be able to set payment frequencies, such as making payments every 15 days.
```

I'm aware that Stripe offers a subscription service, but my scenario involves variable payment amounts, and I'm not the one receiving payments; it's the clients who are receiving them.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to implement this functionality using Stripe? Any advice, code snippets, or pointers to relevant Stripe features or APIs would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your first and last requirement look like the exact same to me - but hey, less requirements is easier for me.

You can still use Stripe Subscriptions to do this, it would be very simple provided your customers can’t freely change the frequency of payments *whilst* their Subscription is going.
Using price_data, you can generate unique Prices for each Subscription, with unique frequencies:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-items-price_data

You would just need to let your customer select their frequency in days, then pass that input as price_data.recurring.interval_count.

Note that Subscriptions infer more fees than just Stripe payments.
If budget is tight, you can always build your own recurring system, then use Stripe’s recurring payments integration to save and charge payment methods:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment